# Power BI - How can I create a measure aggregation from two tables?

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization

I've got two tables Fauna_Afetada (animals affected) e Municipios (all cities of the country). A fauna afetada tem a sigla_uf (state initials which the city belongs to) e nome_municipio (name of the city), as well as the Municipios table.

- I'd like to create a measure counting the number of deaths (Situação_Int = 0 in table Fauna_Afetada, specify that the animal died) by city (table Municipios). The way to join these tables is by using two columns (the sigla_uf and nome_municipio), because each Municipio in Fauna_Afetada might appear several times. How do I do that?
- I'd like to create a measure with the name of the city with the highest number of deaths.

Anyone could help?

The data model is below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a data modeling issue in the first galce,
The model is full of bidirectional relationships that lead to not expect calculations behaviors.

Can you share the file or part of it